# Titanium Appcelerator iPhone App - App crashes when the table view is scrolled close to 1000th record and slows down when it starts scrolling

Tags: iphone, uitableview, titanium, appcelerator-mobile

We have a sample app that loads 10 records each from the db and shows in a table vioew. The next ten records are taken when the scroll reaches the bottom (like the sample of dynamic scroll view in kitchen sink and following the same sample code). However the app scrolling becomes slower and slower when the no of records increases and then crashes when we were showing close to 1000th record. We have even more records to show (10000) and all the rows shows an 50X50 image and two texts.

```
if (search.value != null && search.value != ''){
    dbrows = db.execute('select id, name, scientificname from siteRecords where name            like \'%' + search.value + '%\' order by commonname limit 10 offset ' + lastRow);
}else{
    dbrows = db.execute('select id, name, scientificname from siteRecords order by name    limit 10 offset ' + lastRow);
}

tsEnd = new Date;
var duration = tsBegin.getTime() - tsEnd.getTime();
perfTableView.appendRow({title:"To fetch the record from 0 to " + (lastRow + 20) + " took: " + duration + " ms"});

tsBegin = new Date;
var rowCount = 0;
while (dbrows.isValidRow()) {
    var row;

    if( dbrows.fieldByName('name')[0] != curheader || initHeader == 0){
        initHeader = 1;
        curheader = dbrows.fieldByName('name')[0];
        row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:55,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',backgroundSelectedColor:'#eeee33',hasChild:true,className:'birds',header:curheader});
        index.push({title:curheader,index:rowNumber });
    } else {
        row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({height:55,backgroundColor:'#ffffff',backgroundSelectedColor:'#eeee33',hasChild:true,className:'birds'});
    }

    var lblBirdID = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: dbrows.fieldByName('id'),
        color: '#000000',
        textAlign:'left',
        left:4,
        top:8,
        height:100,
        font:{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:10},
        visible:false
    });
    row.add(lblBirdID);

    media = dbrows.fieldByName('scientificname').replace(' ', '_') + '.jpg';
    var path = Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory + 'Birds/images/'

    if (Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(path,media).exists())
    {
        var f;

        if (isAndroid){
            f = '../images/' + media;
        }else{
            f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'Birds/images/' + media);
        }

        var imgBird = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:f,
            left:4,
            height:50,
            width:50
        });
        row.add(imgBird);
    }else{
        var f;

        if (isAndroid){
            f = '../images/no_bird.jpg';
        }else{
            f = f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory,'Birds/images/no_bird.jpg');
        }

        var imgBird = Ti.UI.createImageView({
            image:f,
            left:4,
            height:50,
            width:50
        });
        row.add(imgBird);
    }

    var lblBirdName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: dbrows.fieldByName('name'),
        color: '#000000',
        textAlign:'left',
        left:60,
        top:8,
        height:20,
        font:{fontWeight:'bold',fontSize:16}
    });
    row.add(lblBirdName);

    var lblBirdScientificName = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text: dbrows.fieldByName('scientificname'),
        color: '#000000',
        textAlign:'left',
        left:60,
        top:26,
        height:20,
        font:{fontSize:11}
    });
    row.add(lblBirdScientificName);

    birdRows[rowNumber] = row;
    rowCount = rowCount + 1;
    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1;
    dbrows.next();
}
dbrows.close();
db.close();

if (rowCount == 20){
    lastRow = lastRow + 20;
}else{
    lastRow = lastRow + rowCount;
}

birdTableView.setData(birdRows);
birdTableView.index = index;

tsEnd = new Date;
duration = tsBegin.getTime() - tsEnd.getTime();
perfTableView.appendRow({title:"To loop through the DB rows and to create table rows took: " + duration + " ms"});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried unloading items at the top, as items are added to the bottom (and vice versa)? Doing something like this would mean there are never more than say 100 rows at any one time.

Also, if possible, use a standard row instead of a custom row. A standard row is MUCH more performant than a custom one.

Comment: How does i do removal of top rows and retaining only 100 rows. I dont think it is possible in appclerator. About the standard row.. i am tetsing the same right now..  i see a performance increase (app didnt crash yet.. i am on row 1600) but the slow is still getting slower and slower.

Comment: [deleteRow](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableView.deleteRow-method.html). One way to make logic like this easier, for adding and removing rows, is to add a custom attribute to each row. Then, use that custom attribute to determine what needs to be loaded on the rows above or below.

Comment: i found that when i comment adding imgBird (image) then it loads much faster. I cant live without images there. Is it something to do with the code i have written

Comment: Can use a "Simple" TableView with the "rightImage" or "leftImage" property? I think that is going to be your best bet as far as performance. Examples [here](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Using+TableViews#UsingTableViews-The%27Simple%27TableView).

Comment: Do you have sample to delete the rows using custom attributes.. We tried SimpleTableView and it is better now.. But however we would like the app to use as less memory as possible there by deleting the rows that are not in visible area

Comment: I do not have a sample off hand, but here is the basic idea: You are loading a list of birds, ordered alphabetically by name. You could [add a custom attribute](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/117344/tableview-help-with-data#answer-204422) to each row called "letter". To make it simple, add and remove all rows with a given "letter". For example, on first load, only show A-D. When the user gets to the bottom of the list, grab the "letter" off the last row, and load in the next letter rows. At the same time, get the letter in the first row, and delete all rows that match it.